# Excel Table: Always Show / Sticky Total Row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table with summed-up values in the total row. To see it, I always have to scroll to the bottom of the table. Is there a state-of-the-art way for always showing the total row? I could imagine a frozen bottom row or a positioning of the totol row at the table heading.

The only solution I found is to create an external total row above the table heading. It refers to the table's total row. Then, I can freeze the first two rows. However, this doesn't appear as a meant-to-be way to me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to freeze a bottom row of a table. However, there are some solutions to recreate this behavior.

1. The solution you mentioned yourself is in my opinion the best option, you can create a row total above the table heading and refer it to the table's total row. Then you can freeze the top rows.
2. Another solution is to use the split screen function. To do this select the total row, navigate to the View menu and click on split. This will split your worksheet in two windows. You can then arrange the window to your preference.
3. You can also create a new window by navigating to the view menu and clicking on New window. Then arrange All and select e.g. horizontal. This will open a new Excel window with the same content and arrange the windows. This is in my opinion the least favorable option but it can be handy if you have a second monitor to display it on.